# Set theory Expression Simplification Discrete Maths

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set theory expression I have been struggling to solve. I have tried to use all the laws I know of such as associative lawd commutative laws, distributive laws and so on but to no avail. I was told that the answer should be an empty set but I can not figure it out.

So here is the Question:

Let $X$ be a universal set and $A$, $B$, $C$ be three subsets of $X$. Simplify

$$ \{ [(A \cup B) \cap C]' \cup B' 
\}' \cup C $$

Where $D'$ denotes the complement of any subset $D$ of the universal set $X$.

I cannot understand how to properly solve it or where the subset $D$ comes in. The lecturer didn't explain it either.

Thank you

Comment: If the answer is really supposed to be the empty set, then the expression you wrote is incorrect.

Comment: So is my lecturer incorrect? Where dors the D' come in? What is the answer supposed to give

Comment: I consider it far more likely that you copied something incorrectly. Anyway, as written, it should be obvious it is not the empty set, and if nothing else, you should be able to give an example illustrating that.

Comment: I took a photo of the question on the slide and that's exactly it replicated. I just don't know what to do with it

Comment: The set $D$ is just used as a generic name to illustrate the efect of the $'$ operator, and so it shouldn't be considered along the excercise. Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an arbitrary object $x$ and ask ourselves, what properties would it need to have to be a member of this new set.

Well, we essentially have the following information $$\textrm{mess}\cup C$$So, we know that for $x$ to be a member of this set, which I will denote from now on as $S$, $x\in C$ or $x\in\textrm{ mess}$. Let's take a closer look at the mess.

Without loss of generality, when looking at the mess, we can assume $x\notin C$ since if $x\in C$, $x\in S$.

So, $$(A\cup B)\cap C=\varnothing$$which implies the mess becomes $$(\varnothing'\cup B')'=(X\cup B')'=X'=\varnothing$$

Hence, we know that $x\notin \textrm{mess}$. Hence, $$x\in S\Longleftrightarrow x\in C$$

Comment: Hi @RushabhMehta, I was wondering where the term 'mess' came from? And is the answer thus an empty set? Although I thought others have said that the answer to this shouldn't be an empty set.

Comment: Ok, I now understand that the answer is union C? But how did you get `code` $$ (X \cup B')' = X' $$ when I thought it should be `code` $$ (X' \cup B} $$?

Comment: @Eddy99 I mean, it's pretty obvious that you haven't taken time to sit down and write it all out the way I did. It'll become trivially obvious once you do so.

Answer (score 0):

The point of $D$ is that if $D$ is  $any$  subset of $X$ then $D'$ is $defined$ to mean the complement of $D$ in $X.$

First, observe that if $D$ is any subset of $X$ then $(D')'=D. $

Second,  observe that if $F$ and $G$ are any subsets of $X$ then $(F \cup F)'=F'\cap G'.$ So we have also  $(F'\cup G')'=(F')'\cap (G')'=F\cap G.$

For brevity  let $D=[(A\cup B)\cap C].$

Therefore

$$\{D'\cup B'\}'\cup C= \{\;(D')'\cap (B')'\;\}\cup C=$$ $$=\{\;D\cap B\;\}\cup C=$$ $$=\{\;[(A\cup B)\cap C]\cap B\;\}\cup C=$$ $$=\{\;(A\cup B)\cap B]\cap C\;\}\cup C=$$ $$=\{\;B\cap C\}\cup C=C.$$